# Sencha Touch 2 and Blackberry OS 7: TabPanel Buttons Misrendering

Tags: blackberry, sencha-touch, tabpanel

**The Problem**

The Tab Panel buttons in my Sencha Touch 2 app are displaying incorrectly within my Blackberry OS 7 device.  This is what they look like:

[image]

**Environment Details**

- Blackberry Torch 9810
- Blackberry OS 7.0
- Sencha Touch 2.0.1

**Troubleshooting**

1. I ran the web site in the Blackberry OS 10 Simulator successfully.  The tab icons look fine
2. The buttons look fine in Android and iOS apps.

**Solutions**

I've upgraded my Blackberry Torch I'm testing the site on from 7.0 to 7.1 and the buttons are rendering correctly now, however, that does not solve my problem for folks still on v7.0.  Has anyone gotten this working correctly in 7.0?

Thanks for your help with this!